# Delphi thread not receiving messages

Tags: multithreading, delphi, vcl

I am developing an application with multithreading (RAD Studio XE5). At the start of the application I create a single thread that will live as long as the main form does.

I am able to dispatch messages from the thread to any form that has been created in my application, however I can't find a way to do the opposite, sending a message from the main VCL thread to the worker thread.

When creating the main form I create the worker thread and copy the handle in a public variable:

```
  serverThread := TMyThread.Create(True, ServerPort + 1);
  serverThreadHandle := serverThread.Handle; // SAVE HANDLE
  serverThread.Start;
```

then (from a different form FrmSender) I dispatch a message to the thread:

```
  PostMessage(uMain.serverThreadHandle, UM_LOC_VCLMSG, UM_LOC_VCLMSG, Integer(PStrListVar));
```

This is the thread's Execute procedure:

```
procedure TMyThread.Execute;
var
    (..)
    vclMSG : TMsg;
    str1, str2 : string;
    (..)
begin
    while not(Terminated) do
    begin
        Sleep(10);
        if Assigned(FrmSender) then
          if FrmSender.HandleAllocated then
            if PeekMessage(vclMSG, FrmSender.Handle, 0, 0, PM_NOREMOVE) then
              begin
                if vclMSG.message = UM_LOC_VCLMSG then
                  begin
                    try
                      pStrListVar := pStrList(vclMSG.lParam);
                      str1 := pStrListVar^.Strings[0];
                      str2 := pStrListVar^.Strings[1];
                    finally
                      Dispose(pStrListVar);
                    end;
                  end;
              end;  
        (.. do other stuff ..)
    end;
end;
```

However **PeekMessage()** never returns true as if it was never receiving any message. I've tried changing the parameters to **PeekMessage()**:

```
PeekMessage(vclMSG, 0, 0, 0, PM_NOREMOVE);
```

But with no results.
Any ideas?

Comment: You don't PostMessage to a thread handle, reading the documentation for PostMessage will help.

Comment: Forgot to mention that the thread is derived from **TThread** class

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [MSDN `PostMessage` function documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644944(v=vs.85).aspx):

> Places (posts) a message in the message queue associated with the thread that created the specified window and returns without waiting for the thread to process the message.
>
> To post a message in the message queue associated with a thread, use the PostThreadMessage function.

Thus, you should use [`PostThreadMessage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644946(v=vs.85).aspx):

> Posts a message to the message queue of the specified thread. It returns without waiting for the thread to process the message.

Give special attention to the *Remarks* section. The recipient thread needs a message queue. Force the thread having one by following these steps:

- Create an event object, then create the thread.
- Use the `WaitForSingleObject` function to wait for the event to be set to the
  signaled state before calling `PostThreadMessage`.
- In the thread to which the message will be posted, call `PeekMessage` as shown here to force the system to create the message queue.

  ```
  PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, WM_USER, WM_USER, PM_NOREMOVE)
  ```
- Set the event, to indicate that the
  thread is ready to receive posted messages.

Then, when using [`PeekMessage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644943(v=vs.85).aspx), you pass a handle value of `-1` to the function, as documented.

Answer (score 5):

```
PeekMessage(vclMSG, FrmSender.Handle, 0, 0, PM_NOREMOVE)
```

The second argument means that you will only retrieve messages sent to the sender, `FrmSender.Handle`. But you sent the messages to the recipient, `uMain.serverThreadHandle`. This is one reason why `PeekMessage` can never return.

Accessing the VCL from the thread as you do is wrong. The form's handle is subject to VCL window re-creation and there is a clear race on `HandleAllocated` and `Handle`. So even if you needed to know `FrmSender.Handle`, it would be wrong to ask for it in the thread.

You are actually sending the message to a thread handle rather than a window handle. That means the message is never even sent, another reason why `PeekMessage` cannot return. Had you checked the return value when you called `PostMessage` you would have learnt that.

I'd use either `PostThreadMessage`, or post the message to a window allocated in the thread with a call to `AllocateHWnd`.

Once you do manage to actually send the message, your use of `PM_NOREMOVE` means that the message queue will never be emptied.

Your use of `Sleep` looks very dubious to me. Why not use `GetMessage` and so block until a message arrives. Anytime you see a call to `Sleep`, be very suspicious.

Your cast to `Integer` will lead to pointer truncation in a 64 bit build. The correct type to cast to is `LPARAM`.

I expect there are other mistakes, these are just the ones I could see in a quick 2 minute scan.

Comment: Didn't know about the Integer() cast problem on x64 builds. Thanks!

Comment: You really need to fix all the other issues too

Comment: Not only is the code subject to a window recreation race, but also another problem is that one thread simply cannot get messages for a window that belongs to another thread (unless you use a message hook via `SetWindowsHookEx()`). Only the thread that creates the window can receive messages for that window. Note also that `AllocateHWnd()` is not thread-safe and should not be used outside of the main thread.

Comment: I always forget that because I'm using a version that is threadsafe

Comment: Actually there is a mistake in my question because I was under the impression that the second parameter to **PeekMessage()** was the handle of the form the message was coming from. I am now passing 0 and retrieving any message to the thread since it does not have any forms of its own.

Comment: Can @RemyLebeau elaborate on the "window recreation race"?

In my application I am doing extensive use of **PostMessage()** from the thread to the forms (in the main VCL thread) and I always use this:

Comment: `if Assigned(frmDestination) then
if frmDestination.HandleAllocated then
PostMessage(frmDestination.Handle, UM_LOC_THREADMSG, UM_MYEVENT, LPARAM(pStrVar));`

Comment: That's wrong. That's the race I talked about. You know what a race is? Use AllocateHWnd like I said.

Comment: And yes there were loads more errors in you code that I picked up, beyond what you specifically asked and what was said in the answer you accepted.